# Proof that $L^p$ functions define tempered distributons

Tags: distribution-theory, schwartz-space

My question here relates to an argument that I have seen used many a time, for example to prove that $\mathbb{L}^p$ spaces define tempered distributions in the following sense : $\varphi \mapsto \int \varphi f$ is a tempered distribution for $f \in \mathbb{L}^p$

The argument is, if $f \in \mathbb{L}^p$ then for any function $\varphi \in \mathbb{L}^q$ (hence for any Schwartz function) 
$$
 |\varphi (x)|=(1+|x|)^{N+1} \cdot |\varphi (x)| \frac{1}{(1+|x|)^{N+1}} 
$$
 where $N$ is the dimension of the euclidean space, and $|\cdot |$ denotes the euclidean norm. Then, $\frac{1}{(1+|x|)^{N+1}}$ is in $\mathbb{L}^q$ and one can write 
$$ ||\varphi (x)||_q \leq \sup|(1+|x|)^{N+1} \varphi (x)| \cdot ||\frac{1}{(1+|x|)^{N+1}}||_q $$

What I don't get is how this $\sup$ expression can be upper-bounded by any of the Schwartz norms since $(1+|x|)^{N+1}$ may well not be a polynomial of $x$ with whole powers because of the square root.
Especially confused as I've just worked out that $|x|^{|\alpha|} \geq |x^\alpha|$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by "define". Do you mean every $L^p$ function can be identified as a tempered distribution?

Comment: Yes exactly. Let me make that clearer

Comment: From $(1+|x|)^2\leq 2(1+|x|^2)$ you can obtain for instance $(1+|x|)^N\leq 2^{\frac{N}{2}}(1+|x|^2)^{\frac{N}{2}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is in fact a tempered distribution, we need to verify whether $f$ acting on Schwatz class test functions produces a finite number, i.e. for $\phi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$
\begin{equation}
  |\langle f,\phi \rangle | < +\infty
\end{equation}
To see this, observe that by Schwartz inequality,

$$\begin{eqnarray} 
|\langle f,\phi \rangle |&=& \bigg|\int f \phi \bigg|      \nonumber \\
                         &\leq&  \int \big|f \phi \big|  \nonumber \\
                         &\le& \bigg(\int \big|f \big|^p\bigg)^{1/p} \bigg(\int 
                            \big| \phi \big|^q\bigg)^{1/q} \text{ where } \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q}=1\\
                         &=& C_f || \phi||_{L^q} \text{ where } C_f=||f||_{L^p}\\
                         &<& +\infty \text{ as } \phi \in L^q
\end{eqnarray}$$