# $\Delta u=3u$ then $u\equiv0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I have the following question in which it is easy to use Fourier transform to get the answer if the function is nice enough, for example $u\in C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, however here $u$ is only in $L^{1}$. How can I get through this?

The question: Let $u\in L^{1}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)$ so that $\Delta u=3u$
in the distribution sense. Prove that $u\equiv0$.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think you cannot use the Fourier transform in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JustDroppedIn's answer works fine for $u\in L^1$. Here is why: Since $\Delta u=3u\in L^1$, it is a [tempered distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968183/proof-that-lp-functions-define-tempered-distributons). Hence we can test against functions $\phi\in\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. If we do so, we get
$$
\langle \phi,\widehat{\Delta u}\rangle=\langle \Delta \hat \phi,u\rangle=-4\pi^2\langle \widehat{|\cdot|^2\phi},u\rangle=-4\pi^2\langle \phi,|\cdot|^2\hat u\rangle.
$$
Thus $\widehat{\Delta u}(\xi)=-4\pi^2|\xi|^2\hat u(\xi)$ without any additional differentiabiliyt assumption on $u$. From here on you can proceed exactly as suggest by JustDroppedIn.

Comment: Thanks for good explanations.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Fourier transform for any $L^1$ function, since it is defined as an operator from $L^1$ to $L^\infty$ (or $C_0$ to be more precise); moreover, it is a continuous operator.

Let's use the Fourier transform: We have $\hat{\Delta u}(\xi)=\displaystyle{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-2\pi ix\cdot\xi}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_j^2}(x)dx=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}(-2\pi i\xi_j)^2e^{-2\pi ix\cdot\xi}u(x)dx=-4\pi^2\|\xi\|^2\hat{u}(\xi)}$, hence $-4\pi^2\|\xi\|^2\hat{u}(\xi)=3\hat{u}(\xi)$ and that holds for all $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n$. This forces $\hat{u}$ to be identically $0$, hence $u\equiv0$, since the Fourier transform is injective.

Comment: Well, I figured since the Laplacian was defined, u would be at least twice differentiable. The case that $u$ is not differentiable (or a.e. differentiable) is beyond my knowledge. I would advise you to specify it in your question that you are talking about a more general case.

Comment: As I mentioned the difficult part is $u$ only $L^{1}$, not $C^{2}$.

Comment: You mentioned that the difficult part is that u is not $C^\infty$